# Join 2 tables, print data from 2nd table when joined rows occur

Tags: mysql, join, logic

**The case:**
I have 2 tables, 'contracts' and 'members' tied with contract.id = members.cid. 
Each contract has one main member and several secondary members (usually the children and spouse of the main member). The main member's details (name, address etc) are stored in table contracts whereas, extra members details are kept in table members. (bad logic, i know but this was a mess to begin with and i need time to redesign the db and website)

**The desired output:**
When I run a batch print of all contracts (lets say, every Friday) I need to also print a copy of the contract for each member, too but with the member's details on the contract instead of the main member.

**The question:** 
How does this translate into a mysql query? Ok, its a left join, **but how do I say "*print data from table `members` instead of `contracts` for the joined rows*"?**

Main fields that occur in the 2 tables are name + surname, those should be enough for a draft query example.

Example tables and data:

```
contracts
-------------------------
id  |  name  | surname | 
-------------------------
1   |  Tom   | Jones   |
2   |  Jamie | Oliver  |

members
--------------------------------
id  |  cid |  name  | surname | 
--------------------------------
1   |   1  |  Jack  | Jones   |
2   |   1  |  Anne  | Jones   |
3   |   2  |  Cathy | Wilson  |
```

So the results I want shoudld be:

```
cid | name   | surname |
--------------------------
1   |  Tom   | Jones   |
1   |  Jack  | Jones   |
1   |  Anne  | Jones   |
2   |  Jamie | Oliver  |
2   |  Cathy | Wilson  |
```

If i write

```
SELECT c.name as name, c.surname as surname, m.name as name, m.surname as surname
FROM contracts c
join members m on c.id = m.cid
```

I simply end up with 
name and name_1, surname and surname_1 but I want ALL names to fall under name and likewise for all other matching columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I finally did and it worked (field names are different but the syntax is what matters):

```
SELECT u.id, u.onoma_u, u.name_u,
       coalesce(u.programa, aa.programa) as programa,
       coalesce(u.barcode, aa.barcode) as barcode,
       coalesce(u.plan, aa.plan) as plan,
       coalesce(u.im_exp, aa.im_exp) as im_exp,
       coalesce(u.symb, aa.symb) as symb
       FROM (SELECT a1.id, a1.onoma_u, a1.name_u, a1.programa, a1.barcode, a1.plan, a1.im_exp, a1.symb
       FROM aitisi a1 
        UNION
           SELECT a2.id, m.name, m.surname, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
           FROM members m
        JOIN aitisi a2 ON a2.id = m.symbid) u
       JOIN aitisi aa ON aa.id = u.id;
```

I used aliases and NULLS as dummy fields to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works :::

```
select c1.id, c1.name, c1.surname 
from contracts c1
union 
(Select m.id, m.name, m.surname 
  from 
members m left join contracts c on (c.id = m.cid))
```

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear in my question... I know how to write a join query but how do I say "print data from table members instead of contracts for the joined rows"?

Comment: Exactly what I need. I shall look into the union statement more, seems quite powerful. Thank you mate.

Comment: Appears I spoke too soon... When I try to include additional columns from table contracts I get MYSQL ERROR: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns so I'm stuck again. Perhaps I need a join query instead?

Comment: changed again, make it compatible to ur requirement.

Comment: the concept of union is that the number of columns in the first select should be exactly same and equal to the second select::
For eg:

Select t1.column1, t1.column2....t1.columnN
from table1 t1
UNION 

Select t2.column1, t2.column2....t2.columnN
from table2 t2:


As you are aligning the rows on one upon another...